# Timestamp stored as character varying : request greater than

Tags: postgresql, playframework-2.2, ebean

I have timestamps stored as varchar in my Postgres DB.
I try to fetch items of the last 24 hours.

This does not fetch my rows. I don't know why it does not work, and how to debug or how to do another way.

```
"SELECT position.id AS positionId "
            + "FROM position "
            + "WHERE totem_id = :totem_id "
            + "AND token IS NULL "
            + "AND to_number(date_post, '999999999')  > :nowMinus24Hrs ";
```

Neither with `cast(date_post as bigint)`

Any idea ?

Comment: Thou shalt not store timestamps as `varchar`!

Comment: So, your `date_post` column is a string (varchar) representation of an integer, which is a Unix timestamp (rather than an integer, or indeed a `date` or `timestamp` column)? And what is the value you are passing in as `:nowMinus24Hrs` (particularly, what data type is it)? And what exactly does "does not work" mean - do you get an error, or just not the desired results?

Comment: date_post is a `varchar` containing a `long`which is a Unix timestamp. To make it cleaner, like have a `date` column, any advices appreciated :) `:nowMinus24Hrs` is a long.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE), your format string (nine `9`s) will take your `date_post` column and only return the last 9 digits. If your dates are from 2001 or later, you'll have 10-digit timestamps.

Comment: Thanks, it fetches right messages